# How to search google with speech recognition from your website?

Tags: javascript, html, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

I have a "Jarvis" or personal assistant in a web browser. It runs on some speech recognition code. I will put at the bottom. I want to tell it to google something, then say what I want it to google, and then get it to automatically google it for me.

Can u please help? 
 just so you know the speech recognition works fine, but the button to activate it isn't shown in the description.

```
<script>

        var x = document.getElementById("reconition");
        var message = document.querySelector('#message');
        var SpeechRecognition = SpeechRecognition || webkitSpeechRecognition;
        var SpeechGrammarList = SpeechGrammarList || webkitSpeechGrammarList;
        var grammar = '#JSGF V1.0;'
        var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
        var speechRecognitionList = new SpeechGrammarList();
                speechRecognitionList.addFromString(grammar, 1);
                recognition.grammars = speechRecognitionList;
                recognition.lang = 'en-US';
                recognition.interimResults = false;
                recognition.onresult = function(event) {
                        var last = event.results.length - 1;
                        var command = event.results[last][0].transcript;
                        message.textContent = 'Voice Input: ' + command + '.';



                        if(command.toLowerCase() === 'google something'){
                                var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('what would you like for me to google');
                window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
                        }
  }




                    };
            recognition.onspeechend = function() {
                recognition.stop();
            };
            recognition.onerror = function(event) {
                message.textContent = 'Error occurred in recognition: ' + event.error;
            }
            document.querySelector('#btnGiveCommand').addEventListener('click', function(){
                recognition.start();
            });
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. If your code works then you have solved your own problem.

Comment: no, i want to google something i say, this only tests for what i say

Answer (score 1):

Well, since you don't specify that there is anything you want to do with the results afterwards you could open a popup/use an iframe and open an google url with the search query. For example:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=this+is+a+test
```

Will open google with the query "this is a test"

the q= parameter is actually responsible for the query.

Now if you want to use the results on your page somehow, an option might be googles custome search api: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

Comment: this could work, but i have already done some stuff like this, i want it to search what i say, and not have to type it in, idk if this if possible, but i want to tell it what to search and my voice detection only listens for certain words.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but can't the web speech api also just take in the whole text without grammer? You definitely need an option to turn your spoken word into text. Otherwise what you want to archive ís not possible. If the web speech api can't do that, there is also Googles Cloud Speech API, but it costs money if you use it more than 60 minutes, so probably not an option for you I guess?

Comment: yea i dont want to spend money, i am just a 13 year old trying to make a cool personal assistante, and i have gotten alot done but i really think this function could be one of the best

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants the answer to this I did figure it out a while ago but forgot to post it.

```
else if (command.includes("Google")){
    var search = command.substring(command.indexOf("+google")+7);
    window.open('https://www.google.com/search?q=' + search, "mywindow", "width=420, height=420, top=0,");
}
```

This opens a new window with a google search of whatever you said after the word google.